# How to remove .git directory while using git clone?

Tags: php, windows, git

As a side project, I want to create a package manager for PHP using Github repositories.

When I run my command:

```bash
absol pickup <git-repo>
```

Under the hood, I run the command with `shell_exec`:

```php
shell_exec("git clone -q --depth=1 $git_repo $path");
```

And all works as expected.

#### Problem:

Now I'm trying to implement a command that will let me delete unwanted packages. When I try to delete files with the `unlink` function I get the error:

> Warning: unlink(.git\objects\pack\pack-83ff79c801011289eaee13a84795a6288641feec.idx): Permission denied

Is there a way to delete these files using PHP on Windows?

P.S. This is just a personal side project as a utility for more side projects. I'm fine with deleting packages manually if this problem cannot be resolved.

Comment: Interesting redevelopment of the wheel?

Comment: As my side projects, I generally reinvent the wheel, .env parsers, or router libraries like Express.js. I have made quite a few and I reuse them a lot. This side project is for "easier" management of said libraries

Answer (score 2):

Since you're dealing with Git-related files, consider using Git commands to delete the files. You can execute Git commands from PHP using shell_exec or other similar functions. For example-

```
shell_exec("git rm --cached path/to/file");
```

As a last resort, you can use the cmd.exe command prompt to delete the files. Use shell_exec to run the del command-

```
shell_exec("cmd /c del path/to/file");
```

Comment: It has removed the files (`package/README.md`, and so on) but the `package/.git` is still intact.

Comment: I see, you may try force remove may be including -rf.

Comment: Like the Linux command `rm -rf` or some git command I'm not aware of

Answer (score 0):

Ansh answer is not entirely correct, but it gave me a push to the right answer:

```php
shell_exec("git rm --cached path/to/file");
```

Removed normal file (`README.md`) but the `.git` directory was still intact and this question focuses on removing the `.git` directory.

```php
shell_exec("cmd /c del path/to/file");
```

This command worked, but I have modified it to delete the whole package directory.

```php
echo "Do you want to remove $package? (dir: '$path')";
shell_exec("cmd /c rmdir /s $path"); // "/s" to delete recursively
```